# property does not exist on type in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am currently learning TypeScript in React so i was working on learning how to make API request with typescript I am fetching a single data by Id the result of the api request is displaying on my web page but i encountered an error the typescript compiler is saying Property does not exits
here is my code

```
import { To, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const SinglePOST = () => {
  type Todo = {
    title: string;
    body: string;
    userId: number;
    id: number;
  };
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isError, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const singleReq = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await axios.get<Todo[]>(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`,
        );

        await setData(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    singleReq();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className=' w-full h-screen bg-slate-900 text-neutral-300 p-4'>
      <div className='w-full flex justify-center '> Single Post {id}</div>
      {loading && <p>...Loading</p>}
      {isError && <p> Error in getting post</p>}

      <div className='text-2xl'> {data.title}</div>
      <div className=' text-xl'> {data.body}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SinglePOST;
```

This is the error it was displaying

**Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Todo[]'**

**Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Todo[]'**

Comment: `data` is an array. You have to use `map` to display each todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your data is a single object but you defined your data as a list of objects.

```
import { To, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const SinglePOST = () => {
    type Todo = {
        title: string;
        body: string;
        userId: number;
        id: number;
    };
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [data, setData] = useState<Todo>();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isError, setError] = useState<any>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const singleReq = async () => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const res = await axios.get<Todo>(
                    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
                );

                await setData(res.data);
                console.log(res.data);
            } catch (err) {
                setError(err);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };
        singleReq();
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <div className=' w-full h-screen bg-slate-900 text-neutral-300 p-4'>
            <div className='w-full flex justify-center '> Single Post {id}</div>
            {loading && <p>...Loading</p>}
            {isError && <p> Error in getting post</p>}

            <div className='text-2xl'> {data?.title}</div>
            <div className=' text-xl'> {data?.body}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set the type to your state as a list of Todo objects, hence the error.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
```

Does your get request return an array of todos?
If yes then you need to map through them:

```js
{
  data.map((todo, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        <div className='text-2xl'> {data.title}</div>
        <div className=' text-xl'> {data.body}</div>
      </div>
    )
  });
}
```

If your get request returns a todo object then you need to change the type on your state:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState<Todo>();
```